# iOS Xcode make background image scale to fill

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, background-image

I want to have the same background for every size of iPhones and iPads using scale to fill mode.

This is my background:

[image]

This is how my Image View looks in Xcode:

[image]

The question is why it doesn't scale to fill when I run this on emulator (iPhone 4s)?

[image]

**Any ideas for this problem?**

Comment: You'll have to use either autolayout constraints, autoresizing masks or code to define its runtime size as well...

Comment: Set auto layout with top right left and bottom to 0 on your ImageView

Comment: problem to setting imageView Constrain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set constrain of imageView as below image. Add adding 4 Constrain.

[image]

OUTPUT :

[image]